# Difference between Clustering and Load balancing?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, cluster-computing

What is the difference between **Clustering** and **Load balancing**?

I know it is a simple question.But I asked this question to several people, But no one gave reliable answer.

Also I googled a lot and can't get an exact answer .

Hope our Stack users will give the best answer for me.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From [Software journal blog](http://standardwisdom.com/softwarejournal/2009/09/clustering-vs-load-balancing-what-is-the-difference/) an extract.

> Clustering has a formal meaning. A cluster is a group of resources
>   that are trying to achieve a common objective, and are aware of one
>   another. Clustering usually involves setting up the resources (servers
>   usually) to exchange details on a particular channel (port) and keep
>   exchanging their states, so a resource’s state is replicated at other
>   places as well. It usually also includes load balancing, wherein, the
>   request is routed to one of the resources in the cluster as per the
>   load balancing policy.
>
> Load balancing can also happen without
>   clustering when we have multiple independent servers that have same
>   setup, but other than that, are unaware of each other. Then, we can
>   use a load balancer to forward requests to either one server or other,
>   but one server does not use the other server’s resources. Also, one
>   resource does not share its state with other resources. Each load
>   balancer basically does following tasks: Continuously check which
>   servers are up. When a new request is received, send it to one of the
>   servers as per the load balancing policy. When a request is received
>   for a user who already has a session, send the user to the *same*
>   server (This part is important, as otherwise user would keep going
>   between different servers, but not able to really do any work). This
>   part is not required for serving static pages, in that case, there are
>   no user sessions.

Answer (score 13):

Clustering means you run a program on several machines (nodes). One reason why you want to do this is: Load balancing. If you have too much load/ work to do for a single machine you can use a cluster of machines instead. A load balancer then can distribute the load over the nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 6):

> A cluster is a group of application servers that transparently run your J2EE application as if it were a single entity.

[Source](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-02-2001/jw-0223-extremescale.html)

> On the infrastructure side, the processing load must be distributed among the group of servers. This is known as server load balancing.

[Source](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2008/jw-10-load-balancing-1.html)

So basically *clustering* is to create a cluster, and *load balancing* is to distribute the load among the nodes in the cluster

Answer (score 2):

**Clustering:**
Clustering is becoming increasingly important in the world of
enterprise application development.just
sharing the application state across multiple Java Virtual
Machines (JVM's)

**Load balancing**
its simple like balaning the request and forwarded to appropriate server for handling the request